Change sorting filter position in DT (DataTable)
I have the following code:
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(dplyr)
library(DT)
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)
#reproducible minimal data frame
YLMI <- structure(list(X = c(511L, 700L, 943L, 1402L, 1429L, 1483L, 1726L, 1834L, 1861L, 2266L), 
                       name = c("Austria", "Belgium", "Bulgaria", "Cyprus", "Czech Republic", "Denmark", 
                                "Estonia", "Finland", "France", "Iceland"), 
                       year = c(2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L), 
                       X1 = c(6.0948572, 5.1031427, 5.145143, 4.3162856, 5.9200001, 6.0751429, 5.8771429, 
                              5.0911427, 4.8957143, 6.262857), 
                       X2 = c(5.7982831, 5.1347985, 4.1193204,3.9259963, 5.9878144, 5.8885102, 5.5807657, 
                              4.5704818, 4.8845162, 5.7285347), 
                       X3 = c(5.8720002, 5.1729999, 4.1079998, 4.7049999, 5.8794999, 6.0700002, 5.3740001, 
                              5.4159999, 5.2164998, 6.3175001), 
                       X4 = c(6.0436354, 3.9714868, 6.0058327, 4.7928214, 4.636817, 6.1576967, 5.9891138, 
                              3.3220425, 3.2921035, 4.1184382), 
                       X5 = c(6.3000154, 5.7192054, 6.5671687, 3.4370663, 6.6064062, 5.8908257, 
                              6.8782973, 4.7578831, 4.3325543, 6.2499504), 
                       X6 = c(4.9257145, 5.5085716, 4.0457144, 3.737143, 2.817143, 5.0228572, 4.0057144, 
                              3.0914288, 5.3942857, 1.7485714), 
                       X7 = c(5.2685714, 5.8857141, 5.1657143, 4.4285712, 6.6914287, 3.7942855, 
                              4.8914285, 5.7142859, 5.2857141, 5.0457144), 
                       X8 = c(5.7268553, 5.3676248, 5.7317734, 5.1083288, 4.9277864, 6.2327962, 
                              6.1439047, 5.5020885, 5.9025269, 5.6717625), 
                       X9 = c(4.7919998, 5.428, 5.1039996, 4.7199998, 5.4880004, 6.2319999, 5.1399999, 
                              5.3560004, 5.4160004, 5.3560004), 
                       X10 = c(4.7384157, 3.7913544, 4.4407039, 5.8613172, 3.5934217, 5.534936, 
                               4.0672798, 4.2066154, 4.3676648, 3.6402931), 
                       X11 = c(5.7328, 5.1810961, 5.4579573, 5.5078635, 5.3274336, 5.7784905, 
                               5.5863309, 5.2231383, 5.3318233, 5.2328768), 
                       X12 = c(5.6389961, 3.9419262, 2.6277056, 4.8922715, 4.4109187, 6.3135815, 
                               5.6100388, 6.3433652, 4.5896773, 6.6938777), 
                       W1 = c(0.0833, 0.0833, 0.0833, 0.0833, 0.0833, 0.0833, 0.0833, 0.0833, 0.0833, 
                              0.0833), 
                       W2 = c(0.0833, 0.0833, 0.0833, 0.0833, 0.0833, 0.0833, 0.0833,
                              0.0833, 0.0833, 0.0833), 
                       W3 = c(0.0833, 0.0833, 0.0833, 0.0833, 0.0833, 0.0833, 0.0833, 0.0833, 0.0833, 
                              0.0833), 
                       W4 = c(0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05), 
                       W5 = c(0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05), 
                       W6 = c(0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05), 
                       W7 = c(0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05), 
                       W8 = c(0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05), 
                       W9 = c(0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125), 
                       W10 = c(0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125), 
                       W11 = c(0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125), 
                       W12 = c(0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125), 
                       indicators = c(12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L), 
                       classes = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A"), 
                       index_constant = c(5.51, 4.9, 4.69, 4.78, 5.12, 5.84, 5.35, 5.02, 4.92, 5.28), 
                       ranking = c(18L, 48L, 59L, 53L, 31L, 7L, 25L, 36L, 45L, 27L)), 
                  row.names = c(511L, 700L, 943L, 1402L, 1429L, 1483L, 1726L, 1834L, 1861L, 2266L), 
                  class = "data.frame")

#helper function:
# ---- Index Calculation Based on User Weights ---- #
calculate_index_w_weights <- function(w1,w2,w3,w4) {
  
  # Obtaining weights
  weights <- array(rep(1,4)) 
  
  # Creating weight matrices to re-calculate the indicator scores.
  w1_matrix <- matrix(weights[1], nrow= 10, ncol=3)
  w2_matrix <- matrix(weights[2], nrow= 10, ncol=5)
  w3_matrix <- matrix(weights[3], nrow= 10, ncol=2)
  w4_matrix <- matrix(weights[4], nrow= 10, ncol=2)
  
  # Unnecessary for now
  YLMI[,c("W1","W2","W3")]<-YLMI[,c("W1","W2","W3")] * w1_matrix
  YLMI[,c("W4","W5","W6","W7", "W8")]<-YLMI[,c("W4","W5","W6", "W7","W8")] * w2_matrix
  YLMI[,c("W9","W10")]<-YLMI[,c("W9","W10")] * w3_matrix
  YLMI[,c("W11","W12")]<-YLMI[,c("W11","W12")] * w4_matrix
  
  ActivityState = YLMI[,c("X1", "X2", "X3")] * YLMI[,c("W1","W2","W3")] #5454x3
  WorkingConditions= YLMI[,c("X4", "X5", "X6", "X7", "X8")] * YLMI[,c("W4","W5","W6", "W7", "W8")]  #5454x5
  Education= YLMI[,c("X9", "X10")] * YLMI[,c("W9","W10")]  #5454x2
  TransitionSmoothness= YLMI[,c("X11", "X12")] * YLMI[,c("W11","W12")] #5454x2
  
  c1 <- rowSums(ActivityState) #5454 x 1 sum(x1*w1....)
  c2 <- rowSums(WorkingConditions)
  c3 <- rowSums(Education)
  c4 <- rowSums(TransitionSmoothness)
  
  w1_i <-rowSums(YLMI[,c("W1","W2","W3")])
  w2_i <-rowSums(YLMI[,c("W4","W5","W6","W7", "W8")])
  w3_i <-rowSums(YLMI[,c("W9","W10")])
  w4_i <-rowSums(YLMI[,c("W11","W12")])
  
  # weighted_index  = YLMI_Nominator / sum_weights
  ActivityState = c1 / w1_i
  WorkingConditions = c2 / w2_i
  Education = c3 / w3_i
  TransitionSmoothness = c4 / w4_i
  
  # Category weighting
  weights_category <- array(rep(0.25,4)) 
  
  # User input on weights
  w_unit <- 1 / (w1+w2+w3+w4)
  weights_category[1] <- w_unit * w1
  weights_category[2] <- w_unit * w2
  weights_category[3] <- w_unit * w3
  weights_category[4] <- w_unit * w4
  
  w1_cat_matrix <- matrix(weights_category[1], nrow= 10, ncol=1)
  w2_cat_matrix <- matrix(weights_category[2], nrow= 10, ncol=1)
  w3_cat_matrix <- matrix(weights_category[3], nrow= 10, ncol=1)
  w4_cat_matrix <- matrix(weights_category[4], nrow= 10, ncol=1)
  
  categories <- data.frame(ActivityState, WorkingConditions, Education, TransitionSmoothness,
                           W1_C=w1_cat_matrix, W2_C=w2_cat_matrix, W3_C= w3_cat_matrix, W4_C=w4_cat_matrix)
  
  categories[is.na(categories) == TRUE] = 0
  
  # If category value is zero, then no weight assigned to that category for the index calculation.
  categories <- within(categories, W1_C[ActivityState == 0] <- 0)
  categories <- within(categories, W2_C[WorkingConditions == 0] <- 0)
  categories <- within(categories, W3_C[Education == 0] <- 0)
  categories <- within(categories, W4_C[TransitionSmoothness == 0] <- 0)
  
  weights_category_sum <-rowSums(categories[,c("W1_C","W2_C","W3_C","W4_C")])
  
  YLMI_Nominator1=categories[,c("ActivityState")] * categories[,c("W1_C")]
  YLMI_Nominator2=categories[,c("WorkingConditions")] * categories[,c("W2_C")]
  YLMI_Nominator3=categories[,c("Education")] * categories[,c("W3_C")]
  YLMI_Nominator4=categories[,c("TransitionSmoothness")] * categories[,c("W4_C")]
  
  YLMI_Nominator = YLMI_Nominator1 + YLMI_Nominator2 + YLMI_Nominator3 + YLMI_Nominator4
  index  = YLMI_Nominator / weights_category_sum
  
  YLMI["weighted_index"]<-index
  YLMI["ActivityState"]<-ActivityState
  YLMI["WorkingConditions"]<-WorkingConditions
  YLMI["Education"]<-Education
  YLMI["TransitionSmoothness"]<-TransitionSmoothness
  
  #creating subset for single indicator scores
  YLMI_IScores <- data.frame(
    Country = YLMI[, c("name")],
    Year = YLMI[, c("year")],
    Classes = YLMI[, c("classes")],
    Index = YLMI[, c("index_constant")],
    Weighted_Index = YLMI[, c("weighted_index")],
    ActivityState=YLMI[, c("ActivityState")],
    WorkingConditions=YLMI[, c("WorkingConditions")],
    Education=YLMI[, c("Education")],
    TransitionSmoothness=YLMI[, c("TransitionSmoothness")],
    UnemploymentRate = YLMI[, c("X1")],
    RelaxedUnemploymentRate = YLMI[, c("X2")],
    NEETRate = YLMI[, c("X3")],
    TemporaryWorkersRate = YLMI[, c("X4")],
    InvoluntaryPartTimeWorkersRate = YLMI[, c("X5")],
    AtypicalWorkingHoursRate = YLMI[, c("X6")],
    InWorkatRiskofPovertyRate = YLMI[, c("X7")],
    VulnerableEmploymentRate =  YLMI[, c("X8")],
    FormalEducationandTrainingRate = YLMI[, c("X9")],
    SkillsMismatchRate = YLMI[, c("X10")],
    RelativeUnemploymentRatio = YLMI[, c("X11")],
    LongTermUnemploymentRate = YLMI[, c("X12")])
  
  # Deleting rows if calculated index is NaN
  YLMI_IScores <- YLMI_IScores[!is.na(YLMI_IScores$Index), ]
  
  YLMI_IScores[is.na(YLMI_IScores) == TRUE] = "-"
  return(YLMI_IScores)
}




##server##
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  #scoreboard
 
  
  #table layout for scoreboard
  sketch <- htmltools:: withTags(
    table(
      class = "display",
      thead(
        tr(
          th(colspan = 3, "Selection", style = "border-right: solid 2px;"),
          th(colspan = 2, "Aggregate Index", style = "border-right: solid 2px;"),
          th(colspan = 4, "Sub-Index Values by Dimension", style = "border-right: solid 2px;"),
          th(colspan = 3, "Dimension: Activity State", style = "border-right: solid 2px;"),
          th(colspan = 5, "Dimension: Working Conditions", style = "border-right: solid 2px;"),
          th(colspan = 2, "Dimension: Education", style = "border-right: solid 2px;"),
          th(colspan = 2, "Dimension: Transition Smoothness", style = "border-right: solid 2px;")
        ),
        
        tr(
          th("Country"),
          th("Year"),
          th("Classes", style = "border-right: solid 2px;"),
          th("Index"),
          th("Weighted Index", style = "border-right: solid 2px;"),
          th("Activity State"), 
          th("Working Conditions"),
          th("Education"),
          th("Transition Smoothness", style = "border-right: solid 2px;"),
          th("Unemployment Rate"),
          th("Relaxed Unemployment Rate"),
          th("NEET Rate", style = "border-right: solid 2px;"),
          th("Temporary Workers Rate"),
          th("Involuntary Part Time Workers Rate"),
          th("Atypical Working Hours Rate"),
          th("In Work at Risk of Poverty Rate"),
          th("Vulnerable Employment Rate", style = "border-right: solid 2px;"),
          th("Formal Educationand Training Rate"),
          th("Skills Mismatch Rate", style = "border-right: solid 2px;"),
          th("Relative Unemployment Ratio"),
          th("Long Term Unemployment Rate")
        ),
        
      )
    )
  )
  
  #data filtering based on user input
  
  filterData <- reactive({
    
    w1 <- input$w_1
    w2 <- input$w_2
    w3 <- input$w_3
    w4 <- input$w_4
    
    
    YLMI_IScores <- calculate_index_w_weights(w1,w2,w3,w4)
    
    rows <- (YLMI_IScores$Country %in% input$country_scb) & (YLMI_IScores$Classes %in% input$country_classes_scb)
    data <- YLMI_IScores[rows,, drop = FALSE]
    data2 <- datatable(data, rownames = FALSE, container = sketch,
                       options = list(info = TRUE, order= list(3,"dsc"), pageLength = 50,
                                      columnDefs = list(list(targets = "_all", className = "dt-center")))) %>%
      formatStyle(c(3,5,9,12,17,19,21), `border-right` = "solid 2px") %>%
      formatStyle(columns = "Index", backgroundColor = "#fdb9c4") %>%
      formatStyle(columns = "Weighted_Index", backgroundColor = "#f72a66") %>%
      formatStyle(columns = "ActivityState", backgroundColor = "#fff9ee") %>%
      formatStyle(columns = "WorkingConditions", backgroundColor = "#fff9ee") %>%
      formatStyle(columns = "Education", backgroundColor = "#fff9ee") %>%
      formatStyle(columns = "TransitionSmoothness", backgroundColor = "#fff9ee") %>%
      formatRound(columns = c(4:21), digits = 2)
    data2
    
  })
  
  output$scb_table <- DT::renderDT({
    filterData()
  })
  
  
  
}


##ui ##
 
ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
  #scoreboard
               sidebarPanel(
                 pickerInput(
                   inputId = "country_scb",
                   label = "Select country/countries",
                   selected = unique(sort(YLMI$name)), # Default selecting all the countries here! TODO
                   choices = unique(sort(YLMI$name)),
                   multiple = TRUE,
                   options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE)
                 ),
                 
                 awesomeCheckboxGroup(
                   inputId = "country_classes_scb",
                   label = "Filter countries by data availability:", 
                   choices = unique(sort(YLMI$classes)),
                   selected = unique(sort(YLMI$classes)),                         
                 ),
                 ######  ----- Weight Buttons ---- #####
                 # Weight Arangements 1
                 sliderInput("w_1",
                             label = "Select weight of Dimension Activity State:",
                             min = 0,
                             max = 3,
                             value = 1,
                             step=1,
                             sep = ""
                 ),  
                 
                 # Weight Arangements 2
                 sliderInput("w_2",
                             label = "Select weight of Dimension Working Conditions:",
                             min = 0,
                             max = 3,
                             value = 1,
                             step=1,
                             sep = ""
                 ),  
                 # Weight Arangements 3
                 sliderInput("w_3",
                             label = "Select weight of Dimension Education:",
                             min = 0,
                             max = 3,
                             value = 1,
                             step=1,
                             sep = ""
                 ), 
                 # Weight Arangements 4
                 sliderInput("w_4",
                             label = "Select weight of Dimension Transitional Smoothness:",
                             min = 0,
                             max = 3,
                             value = 1,
                             step=1,
                             sep = ""
                 )
               ),
               mainPanel( 
                 # Show data table   
                 DT::dataTableOutput("scb_table")
                 
               )
             )
           )


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)

That produces the following output:

However, I want to add the possibility to sort my values, but modifying the parameter ordering = FALSE, the sorting filter appears at the same height of the column name, while I wish to achieve a similar result:

How can I do that?

It is possible by adding some css properties one the two triangles elements.
It will affect all tables of your app. If you want to affect only one table, add the html id of the table in front of each css element.
css_str <- HTML(" table.dataTable thead>tr>th.sorting:after,
table.dataTable thead>tr>th.sorting_asc:after,
table.dataTable thead>tr>th.sorting_desc:after,
table.dataTable thead>tr>th.sorting_asc_disabled:after,
table.dataTable thead>tr>th.sorting_desc_disabled:after,
table.dataTable thead>tr>td.sorting:after,
table.dataTable thead>tr>td.sorting_asc:after,
table.dataTable thead>tr>td.sorting_desc:after,
table.dataTable thead>tr>td.sorting_asc_disabled:after,
table.dataTable thead>tr>td.sorting_desc_disabled:after {
content: '▼' / '';
bottom: 0% !important;
top: auto !important;
}
table.dataTable thead>tr>th.sorting:before,
table.dataTable thead>tr>th.sorting_asc:before,
table.dataTable thead>tr>th.sorting_desc:before,
table.dataTable thead>tr>th.sorting_asc_disabled:before,
table.dataTable thead>tr>th.sorting_desc_disabled:before,
table.dataTable thead>tr>td.sorting:before,
table.dataTable thead>tr>td.sorting_asc:before,
table.dataTable thead>tr>td.sorting_desc:before,
table.dataTable thead>tr>td.sorting_asc_disabled:before,
table.dataTable thead>tr>td.sorting_desc_disabled:before {
content: '▲' / '';
bottom: 10px !important;
}
")

ui <- fluidPage(
    tags$head(
        tags$style(css_str)
    ),
    sidebarLayout(
    # complete with the sidebarLayout code
    # ....
    )
  )

